# Is string indirectly an array?

Tags: arrays, string, reference

So I was learning how to code, And I was learning about memory allocation and how all types of data are stored in variables, since knowing about that ...
I was wondering whether **string is synonymous to a array or not?**

Comment: in what programming language

Comment: Any but, but let's assume here I mean java.